# Bot framework custom actions not working in Teams channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, middleware

I have an existing bot developed using Bot framework Composer and having 2 custom actions written in C# middleware. This is working fine in the directline channel.

We wanted the same bot to be deployed to Microsoft Teams so users can use the bot via Teams.

The same bot isn't working in Teams channel. When I tried disabling the custom actions and removing from appsettings it worked.

Is there any documentation which guides on how we can incorporate custom actions in Teams?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: I just need guidance on developing a bot using custom actions which works in Microsoft Teams channel. probably a sample or documentation stating the same would help.

Comment: Here are some step-by-step guides to help you build different types of bots:
1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-teams-conversation-bot?tabs=dev
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-notificationbot?tabs=vscode